# IlMerge in VSTO project results in FindRibbons error

Tags: vsto, ilmerge

I created a fresh VSTO project .NET 4.5.1 (Outlook) and setup IlMerge using the tutorial [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx).

After the failure I looked in the bin/debug and `OutlookAddIn8.dll` is there so I'm not sure how it's having a problem finding it. Is there something specific I need to do for VSTO projects?

```
Error   1   The "FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'OutlookAddIn8, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'OutlookAddIn8, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```